# How do I create batch file that opens windows command script file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried to search a lot but couldn't find any answer.
I have a windows command script file (anySoftware.cmd) which I'm trying to open it by a batch file.

I tried:

```
start "C:\myPath\anySoftware.cmd"
```

And:

```
start cmd.exe "C:\myPath\anySoftware.cmd"
```

And:

```
start anySoftware.cmd "C:\myPath"
```

All is not working.

Appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried without any command in front of the file path, just `"C:\myPath\anySoftware.cmd"`

Comment: I see you didn't read the help for the `START` command. Regardless of that the only reason you would need to use the `START`  command is if you were running multiple scripts in parallel. Otherwise you can just define the path to the batch file and call it good.  If you need control passed back to the parent batch file then you need to use the `CALL` command. `CALL "C:\myPath\anySoftware.cmd"`

Comment: Thanks guys, just deleting the "start" has opened the file successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution:

```
"C:\myPath\anySoftware.cmd"
```

---

This works, too:

- `CALL "C:\myPath\anySoftware.cmd"` - [Read more](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) about `CALL`
- `START "" "C:\myPath\anySoftware.cmd"` - [Read more](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) about `START`